Do iOS Share Extensions work on a "Designed for iPad" App on Mac?
So I have a cross platform app that runs on iPad and MacOS as "Designed for iPad". That app has a share extension to receive a number of file types that the app can use.
Everything is running kinda smoothly on iPad (it seems to work) - but the Share Extension does not show on the Mac at all when opening the Share Menu (eg in Finder).
The Extension however shows in System Settings Under Privacy -> Extensions -> Added Extensions and "Sharing" is checked for it.
I did not find any documentation on the topic... and a Google search for "designed for iPad" and "Share Extentions" did not show any results either...
Do iOS Share extensions generally work when the app is installed on MacOS?
If yes - what could be the reason that it does not show?
If not - how can I share files with an "Designed for iPad" App?
Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Yes, they work, see my app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/locally-device-ecosystem/id6475152818. I don't remember doing anything special for it to work on the target Mac (Designed For iPad), it just worked right from the start.
One thing I remember is that it didn't work (my app didn't appear in the list) when I tried to debug the extension for this target, meaning to run it on my Mac in photos app. To overcome this I did some completely chaotic things - cleaned build dir; tried to run on Safari, Photos, Finder; changed the order of items in Info.plist and eventually it worked. I still need to go through these things while debugging, but I believe this is some kind of bug/quirk of Xcode and debugging this kind of apps.

I did not get it to work. It works on iOS devices, but not on the Mac - even after distributin the app through TestFlight and installing it. Unfortunately this stuff is not especially debug friendly...

Maybe silly question, but are you sure you the platform "MacOS (Designed for iPad)" is enabled for the share extension too?

It looks like it should, but I did not get it to work. The behavior in System Settings -> Privacy is inconsistent. It sometimes shows and then it does not or it shows in Added Extensions but not in Sharing, or it shows once in Sharing after I enable sharing in Added Extensions. But it never works. Works like a charm on iOS.
